# Отличие WebApplicatIoninitializer от AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet

Настроить ServletContext в Spring можно создав класс - конфигурацию и :

- реализовать интерфейтс WebApplicatIoninitializer и переопределить метод
  onStartup;
- унаследовать класс AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.

Какой способ применять предпочтительнее и в каких случаях? В первом примере можно задать параметры контекста, установить фильтры, например на кодировку. Второй способ не выглядит таким гибким. Привидите, пожалуйста, примеры правильного использования настроек контекста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты в вопросе частично ответил сам. Реализовав интерфейс *WebApplicatIoninitializer* ты можешь полностью сконфигурировать контекст, но вручную. Расширяя *AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer* ты получишь почти готовый контекст сервлета, тебе остаётся реализовать методы *getRootConfigClasses()* и *getServletConfigClasses()*, как это указано в документации.

Первый способ можно использовать, когда нужен полный контроль над процессом инициализации контекста сервлета, второй - когда достаточно стандартного процесса инциализации. Это применимо и к другим абстрактным реализациям *WebApplicatIoninitializer*.